# How can I conditionally add several values to a type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this type:

```js
export type SupportedSourceLanguages =
  | LanguageISOCode.En
  | LanguageISOCode.Es
  | LanguageISOCode.Pt
  | LanguageISOCode.De
  | LanguageISOCode.Ko
  | LanguageISOCode.It;
```

I don't want those last two to be in the type when a condition is met. How can I conditionally add those last two values *only* when the condition is met?

This was my approach (but it's not working):

```js
const environment = 'production'; 

type LiveSupportedSourceLanguages =
  | LanguageISOCode.En
  | LanguageISOCode.Es
  | LanguageISOCode.Pt
  | LanguageISOCode.De;

type DevSupportedSourceLanguages =
  | LanguageISOCode.Ko
  | LanguageISOCode.It;

export type SupportedSourceLanguages = LiveSupportedSourceLanguages extends environment === 'production' ? DevSupportedSourceLanguages : never;
```

Comment: What is `environment` is it variable or type?

Comment: It's a variable

Comment: I updated the sample code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if const's type extends `'production'`:

```
export type SupportedSourceLanguages = typeof environment extends 'production' 
  ? LiveSupportedSourceLanguages 
  : DevSupportedSourceLanguages;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmAbgSwE7gLYNgXhgcgAd0ATAV2CmXHwG4YAoBqAT0LhgBllE4BlMoUIhUUOCT4gyqYHE4BDMAHMy8pXAgwcDGDAA%20BAKJh8O-UYindB-AAUoV8-gAicOk1bsYrxAKEixCSkZOUUVNQ0tMxsAaRBHGwBJB1omOAAPYVEYTw4-LMDJaVkFZVV1TTxckAAzeCQ0TGx4dLEwEk0iUgoqGhgAfi4efkEC8SKQ0vCKmAAubzhfUYDx4JKw8o1aIA)

Comment: If you need to include all of them in dev env: `: DevSupportedSourceLanguages | LiveSupportedSourceLanguages;`

Comment: Isn't the `typeof` here always going to be `string` though? I want to evaluate the value of `environment` and not the type.

Comment: If you have a moment, I have a follow-up question here plz: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69909837/how-do-i-conditionally-add-to-a-record-object-in-typescript

Comment: @zeckdude In order for this to work `typeof environment` should be known at compile time (can't be just `string`)